# JavaScript Object Syntax

Tags: javascript

What is the logic behind this:

object = object = function

I see it a lot in jQuery, for example, 1.4.4 line 99:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
init: function( selector, context ) {
```

or line 332:

```
jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {
```

Why would you use this syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's setting two objects to the same thing: After the statement is evaluated, both jQuery.fn and jQuery.prototype
point to the same object ( `{init: function() {...}}`)

Therefore, jQuery.prototype.init and jQuery.fn.init both point to the same function (because they are both just references to the same object)

The reason jQuery uses this is just for syntactic sugar. Setting jQuery.prototype to an object makes sure that all instances of new jQuery all share the init method from their prototype. jQuery, wanting to be user friendly, creates an alias for you to add new methods to jQuery instances, that alias is jQuery.fn, also knows as $.fn

Comment: So then the above example is the same as typing: jQuery.prototype.fn = {};

Comment: Nope it's the same as: `var obj = {...}; jQuery.fn = obj; jQuery.prototype = obj; delete window.obj`;

Comment: OK, so bear with me here. It is like saying, an object has a function named init, and jQuery.prototype now has a function named init and so does jQuery.fn?

Comment: Yes, remember that they all point to the same thing: jQuery.prototype/jQuery.fn. If you know about C pointers, you can think of them as pointers to the same struct.

Answer (score 3):

The `=` assignment operator works right to left.

So first it assigns the rightmost value to the variable or property to the left of the right most `=`.

Then it continues left and assigns that same value to the variable or property to the left of the next `=` (again, going right to left).

From the [MDC docs for assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators):

> The basic assignment operator is equal (=), which assigns the value of its right operand to its left operand. That is, x = y assigns the value of y to x.

Take this example:

```
var obj = { some:'object' };  // obj is referencing an object

var a,b; // declare a couple of variables

a = b = obj; // now all three are referencing the object referenced by "obj"
```

So it goes like this:

- `obj` is assigned a reference to `{ some:'object' }`
- `b` gets assigned the value of `obj` which is the reference to `{ some:'object' }`
- `a` gets assigned the value of `b` which is now the reference to `{ some:'object' }`

Answer (score 2):

It's assigning the function to both `jQuery.fn` and `jQuery.prototype` (first example) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut for

```
object1 = something;
object2 = object1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers all hit it, its assigning the same values to two objects. The reason why might not be so clear. The second instance is a bit easier to explain. Every member of jQuery.fn is attached to the return value of $(). So if you did the following..

```
jQuery.fn.myFunc = function() { return 'blah'; }
```

You would get

```
$('#blah').myFunc(); // returns 'blah'
```

Extend is a helper function that adding provided object members to the current object. jQuery uses these methods to build up its static (`jQuery.getJSON`) and 'dynamic' ( `$('.class').load()` ) methods. This gives a nice advantage of code separation during development. For example, ajax.js uses jQuery.fn.extend to add its methods of load, serialize, getScript, etc and uses jQuery.extend to add methods like jQuery.ajax